# What does mean sudden "Text file busy" when calling a script?

Tags: linux

```
bash: ./myscript: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Text file busy
```

"myscript" begins with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Just retrying starting it fixed the problem.

Why system program `env` sporadically becomes "busy"? Can it be caused by `prelink` (but cron should start it not at that time...)

Comment: It's not `env` that's busy, it's the script itself. (By an editor or viewer, most likely.)

Comment: Here "busy" means "a process has ./myscript opened for **writing**", according to *execve(2)*. An editor usually does this only while saving edits to disk.

Comment: OK, someone should add this as answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764946/what-generates-the-text-file-busy-message-in-unix has more discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commenters say that it is script busy, not `env` or `python` and is caused by text editor  saving it.

Answer (score 3):

Usualy it's "./myscript" witch is busy because another program modify the file. It can be a text editor (when save it) but also a remote copy (This can be long if the download rate is low) or another program.